# Не могу подключиться к MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@ds125482.mlab.com:25482/dbname', {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected.'))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Выходит ошибка 
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mlab.com:] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED]

Comment: А mongod-сервис запущен?

Answer (score 0):

Либо на этом порту этого адреса не запущен никакой сервис, либо он закрыт фаерволлом. Третьего не дано.

Comment: telnet-ом этот хост/порт телнетятся

Comment: @norbornen Тогда есть ещё два (вернее, три) варианта: 1) либо они *уже* телнетятся; 2) либо с машины, на которй запускается коннект, имя резольвится в другой адрес, нежели у нас с вами; 3) либо фаерволл выборочный. Всё равно сводится к тем же двум.

Comment: Я в этом деле полный новичок, делал все по документации на mLab. Так должно все быть? http://prntscr.com/knpaf9